# Meaning of got out of something

Tags: phrase-usage

is it correct to say I just got out of an interview after being interviewed? Does got out has the meaning of finished?

Comment: It's wrong.....

Comment: To _get out of_ something can have the meaning 'avoided having to do it', so your sentence is potentially ambiguous. I would suggest 'I've just _come_ out of an interview'.

Comment: "got out [of]" ***never*** has the meaning of "finished". It's comprehensible, but unlikely in your context, where it would mean *I just **left** an interview*, Almost certainly after the interview came to a "normal" end, but feasibly the speaker walked out prematurely - all we know for sure is he did in fact leave the location where the interview took place (unless it's being used in @KateBunting's sense of "managed to avoid having to do it", obviously).

Comment: @Sam.  why wrong?  It seems quite normal English to me.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the comments. I think this is a correct usage of "got out of". If I finish a meeting and want to get in touch with somebody else, I'd say something like "hey, I just got out of a meeting, I'm available now".

It's true that it could also mean "I avoided having to do a meeting" depending on context, and if you wanted to avoid that ambiguity, "I just finished a meeting" is clear, but a little more formal.

Comment: I personally wouldn't say "got out of an interview" to mean the interview was canceled or rescheduled, but I would use that for something unpleasant: "I got out of jury duty" or "I got out of having to work the night shift"

Answer (score 1):

To say "I just got out of the interview." meaning you just left the interview is correct.

If someone were to ask you "Did you have to do that interview?" and you responded "No, I got out of it." would also be correct. But means you didn't have to do the interview you thought you did.

Very average and common dialog in the States.